# Multiple bars per ID with respective symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot bar plot where each ID would have 2 bars/groups, and each bar would have their own respective symbols for ongoing, pd, and +B statuses, as well as duration on top of each bars. However, I'm not able to display each group's own status symbols. The text for displaying durations are also a little off. Is it also possible to order the IDs on the X-axis by descending order of group 1 duration?

Thanks!!

Here's my reproducible code so far and the resulting plot.

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id = rep(seq(1:30), 2),
                          group = c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 30)),
                          duration = sample(0:10, replace = T),
                          ongoing = rbinom(n=60, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
                          pd = rbinom(n=60, size=1, prob = 0.5),
                          cat = rbinom(n=60, size=1, prob = 0.5)))


longdf <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(ongoing == 1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time = duration+0.3, type = 'Ongoing') %>%
  dplyr::select(id, group, time, type) %>%
  # PD
  rbind(dplyr::filter(df) %>%
          dplyr::filter(pd == 1) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(time = 2, type = 'PD') %>%
          dplyr::select(id, group, time, type)) %>%
  # cat
  rbind(dplyr::filter(df) %>%
          dplyr::filter(cat == 1) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(time = 3, type = '+B') %>%
          dplyr::select(id, group, time, type)) %>%
  # duration text
  rbind(dplyr::filter(df) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(time = duration+0.1, 
                        type = as.character(round(duration, 1))) %>%
          dplyr::select(id, group, time, type))

typeLevels <- c('PD', '+B')

shapedf <- longdf %>%
  dplyr::filter(type %in% c('PD', '+B')) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(type = factor(type, levels = typeLevels)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(type)) 

textdf <- longdf %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl('\\d+', type))

arrowdf <- longdf %>%
  dplyr::filter(type == 'Ongoing') %>%
  dplyr::mutate(time1 = time-0.1, time2 = time+0.1, type = group, 
                lane.col = 'red') %>%
  dplyr::select(id, group, lane.col, type, time1, time2)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(id, desc(duration)), y = duration)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', aes(fill = factor(group))) +
  geom_point(data = shapedf[shapedf$type %in% c('PD', '+B'),],
             aes(id, time, colour = type, shape = type), size = 2) +
  geom_text(data = textdf, aes(id, time, label = type), size = 2) +
  geom_segment(data = arrowdf, aes(x = id, xend = id, y = time1, yend = time2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, 'cm'), type = 'closed'), size = 1, 
               colour = arrowdf$lane.col, show.legend = F) +
  xlab('') + ylab('Duration\n') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.75, 0.7), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = 'black'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold', angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = 'bold'), legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.2, 'cm'), legend.background = element_rect(color = 'white'),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'), legend.key = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0), limits = c(-0.5, 10), breaks = seq(0, 10, by=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(charcoal, 'dark grey', 'light grey')) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('green', 'orange'),
                      breaks = c('PD', '+B')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(4, 3),
                     breaks = c('PD', '+B')) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 2), shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) 

plot1
```

The plot I get from above code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you have a dodged barchart, whereas you use `position="identity"` for the points, segment and text. Hence, they will not align with your bars.

However, overall you might consider using a different approach by adding the symbols as text labels using unicode symbols and using the `ggtext` package to color the symbols. Additionally, to still get a legend for the symbols I use a fake `geom_point` layer to just add a `shape` and `color` legend:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(seq(30), 2),
  group = rep(1:2, each = 30),
  duration = sample(0:10, 60, replace = TRUE),
  ongoing = rbinom(n = 60, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
  pd = rbinom(n = 60, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
  cat = rbinom(n = 60, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

typeLevels <- c("PD", "+B")

df <- df |>
  mutate(
    id = reorder(id, ifelse(group == 1, -duration, NA), na.rm = TRUE),
    arrow = if_else(
      ongoing == 1,
      "<span style='color: red; font-size: 14pt'>\u2191</span>",
      NA_character_
    ),
    cross1 = if_else(
      pd == 1, "<span style='color: green'>\u271A</span>",
      NA_character_
    ),
    cross2 = if_else(
      cat == 1, "<span style='color: orange'>\u2716</span>",
      NA_character_
    ),
    value = if_else(
      ongoing == 1, duration, NA_real_
    )
  ) |>
  unite(
    "label", arrow, cross1, cross2, duration,
    sep = "<br>", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = duration)) +
  geom_col(
    position = "dodge", aes(fill = factor(group))
  ) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    aes(label = label, group = group),
    position = position_dodge(width = .9),
    fill = NA, label.size = 0,
    vjust = 0
  ) +
  # Fake points to add a shape and color legend
  geom_point(
    data = data.frame(
      type = c("PD", "+B"),
      x = NA_real_,
      y = NA_real_
    ),
    aes(x = x, y = y, shape = type, color = type),
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    breaks = c("PD", "+B"),
    values = c("\u271A", "\u2716")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    breaks = c("PD", "+B"),
    values = c("green", "orange")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dark grey", "light grey")) +
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(order = 2),
    shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", angle = 90),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = "white"),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.key = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0, 0, 2),
    # limits = c(-0.5, 10),
    breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1)
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Duration")
```

[image]